# How to compare dates in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am working on a task manager project, user can define the "ending date" of the task, I would like to change the front end code of a task that isn't completed before the "endind_date".I tried playing  around in models.py but i get back this error:
"can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date"

```
models.py:
class Task(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    importance = models.ForeignKey(Importance, null=True, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    creation_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    ending_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def is_end_date(self):
        if datetime.now() > self.ending_date:
            if not self.complete:
                return True
            else:
                pass
        else:
            pass

html(only included related code to the problem):
 {% if task.is_end_date %}
  #code
{% else %}
 #code
```

Comment: Use `date.today()` instead of `datetime.now()` so you are using a date and not a datetime?

Answer (score 1):

You should convert the `datetime` object to a `date`, by calling `.date()` on it:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

class Task(models.Model):
    # …
    
    def is_end_date(self):
        return now().date() > self.ending_date and not self.complete
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `date.today()` or `datetime.now().date()` as

Using `date.today()` as

```
from datetime import date

def is_end_date(self):
    if date.today() > self.ending_date:
        if not self.complete:
            return True
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass
```

Or `datetime.now().date()`

```
from datetime import datetime

def is_end_date(self):
    if datetime.now().date() > self.ending_date:
        if not self.complete:
            return True
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass
```